# Can't set permissions for USB drives?

Tags: mount, permissions, usb-drive

I'm trying to set permissions for folders on USB drives that I've mounted with Nautilus, but when I change the permission, it just changes right back again.  No error message or any other explanation.  I've tried "Open as administrator" and it still doesn't work.  How do I set the permissions so that they can be accessed as shared folders on the network?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your USB stick is probably using FAT(16/32) or NTFS as file system which doesn't support permissions. That's why they change back after edit in nautilus. If you want to use permissions with USB sticks/drives, you'll need to format it to any EXT formats (use either 3 or 4) using gparted (install with synaptic).

Comment: should add that using EXT file systems can not be read from windows without additional software (like http://www.fs-driver.org/ )

Comment: That's what samba is made for: mounting and sharing FAT32 or NTFS drives.

Comment: @digitaljail: I can access shares of EXT folders from Windows.  It doesn't need any additional software.

Comment: @endolith as Share trough Samba, you right, but if you connect the USB drive to a Windows system for some reason, you need additional software in order to access data on the usb drive.

Comment: and NTFS supports permissions

Comment: @endolith: but not permissions used by UNIX systems.